# django model instance method not being called

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to update my model upon login (to check the authorizations of a person from an external system).

The code of my model looks as follow:

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.db import models

class Person(AbstractUser):
    is_dean = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    is_institute_manager = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    managed_institutes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def get_managed_institutes(self):
        return json.loads(self.managed_institutes)

    def set_managed_institutes(self, value):
        self.managed_institutes = json.dumps(value)


# Signals processing

def check_authorizations(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    ...
    # check if the user is dean
    is_dean = False

    # logic to check if the user is dean...

    user.is_dean = is_dean

    # Check if the user manages institutes
    is_institute_manager = False
    managed_institutes = list()

    # Logic to check if the user is managing institutes ...

    user.is_institute_manager = is_institute_manager
    user.set_managed_institutes = managed_institutes

    user.save()


user_logged_in.connect(check_authorizations)
```

Surprisingly, the boolean flags get set correctly, but the method `set_managed_institute` never gets called...

I am quite convinced this a trivial mistake from my end, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you call methods in Python. You need to do so explicitly:

```
user.set_managed_institutes(managed_institutes)
```

Or did you mean to define a property?

```
@property
def managed_institutes(self):
    return json.loads(self._managed_institutes)

@managed_institutes.setter
def managed_institutes(self, value):
    self._managed_institutes = json.dumps(value)
```

But also note, you probably want to use a JsonField anyway. If you're using PostgreSQL, there is one defined in Django directly; otherwise there are several third-party libraries that take care of serializing and deserializing your data on load/save.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. would you have some third party library to recommend?